# django models self.text attribute not returning the text

Tags: python, django-models

I'm practising on a project from book 'Python Crash Course'

I've created two models with Django, one for **Topics** one for **Entry**

The models have `text` attribute, but it's not displaying neither on the web site nor the admin panel. Rather than the text I've entered, I see:
Topic object (1)
Topic object (2)

I've read the documentation for string formatting and model self methods but couldn't find an answer. I've migrate the database couple times to ensure. Also tried to simplified as
`return self.text` but it didn't worked either. I'm not getting any errors but it's not conventional not seeing the topic title.
Tia

```
from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about"""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a topic"""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

def __str__(self):
    """Return a string representation of the model"""
    return f"{self.text[:50]}"
```

[image: Admin Panel]

Comment: `__str__` should be placed inside `Topic` class.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Thanks it worked, but this should be used as global for other models too according to the book, so should I add this to other models too?